# is it possible to simplify isset?

Tags: php, boolean, conditional-statements, isset

I have a lot of functions with parameter that can be either bool or null. If we simplify my functions I have somethings like this:

```
funtion ($param) {
  if ($param) { 
    //true
  } else { 
    //false 
  }
}
```

However, when I call `function(null);` it obviously goes into else part of condition. So I have to do

```
funtion ($param) {
   if (isset($param)) {
      if ($param) { 
        //true
      } else { 
        //false 
      }
   }
}
```

for every similar `if` condition, which is sort of annoying.

So my question is this:

Is there a possibility to do this type of condition with this type of parameter faster and/or without additional function?

Comment: `if (boolify($param))` should throw an "undefined" error if `$param` isn't defined. Or do you just want to see that it isn't empty?

Comment: So 3 possibilities right? null, true, false

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob I completely screw whole question (edited now), boolify wont be right function for this condition, this is exact mistake that caused huge bug in our project.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited my Q, made huge mistake there, sorry about that.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. `isset()` returns true if the variable is set and isn't null. If you want to see if it is a bool or null, `is_null($param)` or `is_bool($param)`

Comment: `null`, `false` and `true` are different states of a variable, but a `null` variable in an `if` statement will be evaluated as `false`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson As You can see now, I need to check if param is not null before main condition or otherwise it would go into else part if param is null. What I dont like about this concept is two `if`s.

Comment: Remove the first `isset()`. You know that it exists since you have defined it as a function parameter. Or do you want three different things to happen depending on `null`, `true` or `false`?

Comment: @M.I. Exactly, that's my point. How can I do `if () {/*only true*/} else {/*only false*/}` better than it is shown in my example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sort of, $param is often used in other object as variable from session or wherever else so it could be true false if defined but null is also possibility. And I want to do `if` code if its true, `else` code if its false and neither of these if its null.

Comment: I posted an answer that does just that...

Answer (score 3):

To only validate on `true` and `false`, use strict type comparison (===):

```
function check($param)
{
    if ($param === true) {
        // It's true. :)
    } else if ($param === false) {
        // It's false.. :o
    }
}
```

This will ignore it if it is `null`.

Comment: This is exact code I need! Although, just to make sure, is there another way to achieve exactly same output without ` if ($param === false)`? It's  a little bit long line to type for every condition with same input.

Comment: No, not really. How can this line be too long?

Comment: You can always change `$param` to `$p`, if that makes it easier? Btw, if it solves your problem, please mark the answer as solved.

Comment: I know it looks really wierd, but I love to minimize my code as much as possible, I even have function with one line return which checks if array key exists and returns value of key just to avoid if(array_key_exists(...)) {set value of key}, it looks like this:
`return (isset($haystack[$needle])) ? $haystack[$needle] : ($null) ? (array_key_exists($needle, $haystack) ? $haystack[$needle] : null): null;`
So this type of things like else if (...) instead of else matters to me even though they probably should not...

Comment: What you are doing is mean to other coders that might need to edit your code. Using nested ternary operations should actually get you fired. It is a mess within a mess and a really bad practice. Good code is self explanatory, not obscure. You got a working answer. If you want to try to make it more obscure, go ahead, but for now, your question have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

> Please read the bottom code for the most useful (but least explanative) function.

The below function solves your dilemma. If `$param` is true or false then the `return` gives back the boolean version of the `$param` (useful for such instances as if $param is a sting or an integer etc).

else, nothing is returned by the function which is defined as a `NULL` value.

example with type clarity texts:

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$test[] = NULL;
$test[] = true;
$test[] = false;
$test[] = "string";
$test[] = 45;

    function tester($param) {
      if(!is_null($param)){
          return (boolean)$param?"true":"false";
        }
        return "null";
    }

foreach($test as $row){
    print $row . " :: ". tester($row)."\n";

}
```

Exampled Output:

> :: null
>  1 :: true
>   :: false
>  string :: true
>  45 ::
>   true

If you want to return the actual type rather than the textual representation this can be easily achieved with a slimmed down version:

Solution:

```
function ($param) {
      if(!is_null($param)){
          return (boolean)$param;
        }
       // not required but useful to keep for code clarity.
      //return null;
    }
```

Possible results:

> 1 (true)
>  0 (false)
>  null